# Wrong merge fields in Email Template

Tags: email-template, merge-field

I have a **Case** related email notification using a template like below.
In my Case object I also added a Formula custom field, called **Type__c** that renders an icon per each Type.

When the email is sent instead of seeing the Type string field I see the icon (Type__c).
I tried deleting this template and recreate it but I got the same result.

Any idea why the email template is doing so?

```
Hi {!Receiving_User.FirstName}

Please note that case #{!Case.CaseNumber} has been submitted.

Details:

Customer: {!Case.Account}
Subject: {!Case.Subject}
Type: {!Case.Type}
Severity: {!Case.Severity__c}
Priority: {!Case.Priority}

Description:

{!Case.Description}


Link: {!Case.Link}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by "Type__c that renders an icon per each Type". Does it contain the URL of the image? Can you explain a bit more.

Comment: Yes, Type__c is a custom formula field which renders an image using the IMAGE() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just created an email template and a custom text field `Case.Type__c` and can confirm that the custom field "hides" the standard field. Surprising.

The simplest work-around is to ensure that the custom fields you want to present have significantly different names to the standard `Case` fields.

If you can't change the name of `Case.Type__c`, then you can add a formula field (called e.g. `Case.TypeText__c`) of:

```
TEXT(Type)
```

and reference that in the template instead of `Case.Type` to avoid the hiding problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Type: {!Case.Type}
```

If the above is the field you're referring to, sounds like it may be doing what one might expect it to (display an icon for the Case "Type". If you want to see the text string, then you need to use the custom formula field you mention in your template as below:

```
Type: {!Case.Type__c}
```

Comment: its the other way around: Type is the standard SF picklist field and Type__c is my formula field that renders an image

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that you'd put `{!Case.Type}` in the new template when you state you want to see the string that would be in `{Case.Type__c}`. As @KeithC said, the formula needs to evaluate as text. Perhaps that's the issue you're having? I'd have thought it was one of naming with the custom field extension name characters missing. Keith may be correct that you need to make the field name event more distinctly different.

Answer (score 0):

The most optimised and simplest solution will be just to replace the {!Case.Type} or {!Case.Subject} with {!BlankValue(Case.Type, '')}  or {!BlankValue(Case.Subject, '')}  respectively.

Above solution will work fine and will not need any formula field to be created.